# Usar javascript para disparar modal ulkit css

Tags: javascript, css

Segundo a documentação do Ulkit css para exibir uma janela modal temos:

```
    <button uk-toggle="target: #my-id" type="button"></button>

<!-- This is the modal -->
<div id="my-id" uk-modal>
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-body">
        <h2 class="uk-modal-title"></h2>
        <button class="uk-modal-close" type="button"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sendo necessário um botão para disparar a modal. 
Como eu faria para exibir a modal sem a necessidade de um botao.
No caso estaria dentro de uma função javascript e dependendo do resultado de um IF, quero chamar a modal. Exemplo:

```
if(meuValor > 1){
    UIkit.modal("my-id").show();
}
```

Entretando ao fazer isso o sistema me retorna = **"Cannot read property 'show' of undefined"**

Qual seria a maneira de chamar essa modal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode fazer assim por exemplo. Toda vez que o número no `input` for maior que **1** o modal abrirá.

> - O seu código não funcionou pq você não passou o `#` na chamada do modal.
> - Método keyup verifica cada entrada de valor no input e testa a condição no `if`

```js
$(".uk-input").on("keyup", function(){     
  if($(".uk-input").val() > 1)              
  UIkit.modal('#my-id').show();              
})
```

```html
<!-- UIkit CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.10/css/uikit.min.css" />

<!-- UIkit JS -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.10/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.10/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>

<div class="uk-margin">
    <input class="uk-input" type="text">
</div>

<!-- This is the modal -->
<div id="my-id" uk-modal>
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-body">
        <h2 class="uk-modal-title">Teste</h2>
        <button class="uk-modal-close" type="button">X</button>
    </div>
</div>
```